# how would I check for a word a string that has multiple words in a list?

Tags: python, list

I need help looking for a way to check for words within a string that is part of a list, EX:

```
list = ["brown cow", "brown cat", "blue mouse"]
```

How would I search just for the word brown in the strings and be able to get the whole variable name from that to be used in something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter your list by keywords, then you could use `in` with a list comprehension:

```py
list = ["brown cow", "brown cat", "blue mouse"]
output = [x for x in list if "brown" in x]
print(output)  # ['brown cow', 'brown cat']
```

But a safer approach would be to use `re.search`:

```py
list = ["brown cow", "brown cat", "blue mouse"]
output = [x for x in list if re.search(r'\bbrown\b', x)]
print(output)  # ['brown cow', 'brown cat']
```